# Trying to get a String out of an Array (Open Weather Map)

Tags: json, swift, ios8, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to get weather data from the [Open Weather Map API](http://openweathermap.org/current) (json) using swift. I managed to access the temperature using this

```
if let main = json["main"] as? NSDictionary {
    println(main)
    if var temp = main["temp"] as? Double {
        temperatureLabel.text = String(format: "%.1fº K", temp)
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly I am not able to access the weather description! I tried

```
if let weather = json["weather"] as? NSArray {
    println(weather)
    if var temp = weather["description"] as? String {
        descriptionLabel.text = weatherDescription
    }
}
```

I just don't know what to try anymore due to the fact that I am new to Swift and never used json before.

Comment: Please show the request you are doing and how you are doing it.

Comment: Is `weather` an array of dictionaries?  If so, you need to first subscript the array.  Try `weather[0]["description"] as? String`.

Comment: Also you can try to downcast 1st to `AnyObject` before `String` like: `weather["description"] as AnyObject! as? String`

Comment: solved by vacawama, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weather` is an `array` of dictionaries so the `array` needs to be subscripted as following:

```
if let weather = json["weather"] as? NSArray {
    println(weather)
    if var temp = weather[0]["description"] as? String {
        descriptionLabel.text = weatherDescription
    }
}
```